# Using the words sunset and dawn

Tags: prepositions, articles, definite-articles

which of these phrases is correct?

> his practice ends before the dawn/sunset of a day in June

or

> his practice ends before dawn/sunset on a day in June

Comment: Please provide the broader context/passage/text on which this clause will be embedded.

Comment: I think _the dawn_ is usually used to refer to the action of the sun rising, while _dawn_ by itself refers to the time of day when it occurs.

Comment: The usual pairs are sunrise/sunset and dawn/dusk (if you use one of these in a pair, use the other, don't mix. Also, sunrise/sunset are much more common nowadays in AmE. And use 'on' not 'of'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *definite article* is used while being specific. For example, "**the** dawn (sunset) of June 12, 2015", "**the** sunset yesterday was fabulous", etc. No article is used while speaking in a general sense. For example, "dawn is the best time to be on the beach", "sunsets are beautiful in Hawaii" are correct.

Your example is (out of the context and) very general as there're no specifics here. Therefore the following would be considered correct, unless you add more *determiners*:

"before dawn/sunset on a day in June" - "a day" = any day